# Как спарсить текст с проходом по ссылкам

Tags: парсер, powershell

Есть задача спарсить текст (например стихи) с сайта. Структура сайта устроена так, что на странице сайта расположены не сами стихи, а ссылки на них. Мне нужно, чтобы парсер проходил по ссылкам и забирал с них текст стихотворения и записывал в отдельный (или в один общий) текстовый файл.

Пример страницы сайта для парсинга https://stihi.ru/poems/selected.html

Подскажите возможно ли так сделать? Я пытался делать это в Powershell, но у меня все время получалось только спарсить текст только с текущей страницы (но не текст с каждой ссылки).

PS Я новичок и знаю только самые основы...

Comment: вы про этот [powershell](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell)? в python достаточно хороших библиотек для парсинга, не пробовали?

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Python - вне конкуренции :)
Вам понадобятся библиотеки `requests` для запросов и `bs4` для парсинга результатов:

```
pip install bs4
pip install requests
```

Импортируйте их и укажите адрес ресурса:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://stihi.ru'
```

Функция `get_poems_data()` сбора данных:

```
def get_poems_data() -> dict:
    r = requests.get(f'{URL}/poems/selected.html')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    poems_block = soup.find('ul', type='square')
    poems_links = poems_ul.find_all('li')

    poems_data = []
    for row in poems_links:
        data = row.find_all('a')
        poems_data.append({
            'title': data[0].text,
            'author': data[1].text,
            'link': URL + data[0]['href'],
        })

    return poems_data
```

возвращает список словарей с названием, автором и ссылкой:

```
data = get_poems_data()
>>> data
[
    {'title': 'Новый путь', 'author': 'Вадим Бакулин', 'link': 'https://stihi.ru/editor/2021/02/10/617'}, 
    {'title': 'Фонарики', 'author': 'Светлана Севрикова', 'link': 'https://stihi.ru/editor/2021/02/10/150'}, 
    {'title': 'Талая вода', 'author': 'Мила Исаева', 'link': 'https://stihi.ru/editor/2021/02/10/1028'}, 

    ...

    {'title': 'Она пыталась', 'author': 'Иван Грозный', 'link': 'https://stihi.ru/editor/2021/02/08/3106'}, 
    {'title': 'Как лёгок день и радостен покой', 'author': 'Фокеева Елена', 'link': 'https://stihi.ru/editor/2021/02/09/4598'}, 
    {'title': 'Как чудища, блаженные слова', 'author': 'Хубулава Григорий Геннадьевич', 'link': 'https://stihi.ru/editor/2021/02/08/7177'}
]
```

Функция `get_poem_text(poem_link)` пасинга текста:

```
def get_poem_text(poem_link: str) -> str:
   r = requests.get(t_url)

   soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
   text = soup.find('div', class_='text').text

   return text
```

возвращает текст, например, последнего стиха в `data`:

```
>>> print(get_poem_text(data[-1]['link']))

Как чудища, блаженные слова,
Бросаются ко мне голодной стаей,
Строфу железной рифмой подковав,
Я их ловлю и долго приручаю.

Ныряю в детский, сумасшедший гам,
Где смех уже неотличим от стона,
И громко называю, как Адам,
Жар-птицу, саламандру и дракона.

Рычат они, напав на чужака,
Как будто им кошмар докучный снится,
И сами выбирают ездока,
Когда ему готовы подчиниться.

Строптивы, непокорны до конца,
Никто из них добром служить не хочет...
Рождается из схватки пара строчек,
Как золото из серого свинца.
```

И записать в файл:

```
with open(f"{data[-1]['title']}.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(get_poem_text(data[-1]['link']))
```

в директории, откуда запускался файл, будет новый .txt: `Как чудища, блаженные слова.txt`...

Answer (score 0):

> Python - вне конкуренции :)

Был бы, если бы:

1. мог решать большинство задач "из коробки", а не с помощью предварительного `pip install`
2. не было прочих интерпретаторов

`PowerShell` в его нынешнем виде (то есть `pwsh`) способен решать "из коробки" (при наличии рук не из задницы) огромное количество задач. Ну разве что научного характера задачи лучше решаются в `Julia`.

Как поставленная задача может быть решена в `pwsh`?

```
$com = New-Object -ComObject HTMLFile
# берём только первое стихотворение, если нужно скопом - используем foreeach
$com.write([ref](Invoke-WebRequest "https://stihi.ru$((
   Invoke-WebRequest https://stihi.ru/poems/selected.html
).Links.Where{$_.class -eq 'poemlink'}[0].href)").Content)
$com.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].innerText | Out-File C:\somefile.txt -Append
[void][Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($com)
```